# Strange UI View Animation Effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, animation

I've been having this weird issue when trying to do a UI animation between two views in a view controller.

When it goes back to the main menu, the gray bar goes quickly from the middle to the bottom.  It happens to the back button on the 2nd screen, but it's hard to see.  So basically parts inside the views are flying around then going to where they are supposed to be when the animation transition is finished.

I know this code for the animation might look a bit strange, but here's the method to go back to the main menu:

```
- (void)gotoMain_t{

NSLog(@"switch to main");

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {

    for(UIView *v in [containerView subviews]) {
        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeT:finished:context:)];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    MainMenu *mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
    mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(-1024, 0, 1024, 768);
    [containerView insertSubview:mainMenu atIndex:1];


    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.4];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(1024, 0, 1024, 768)];

    mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [mainMenu release];

} 

[UIView commitAnimations];}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The setAnimationDidStopSelector looks weird, it's not clear you need to set it inside a loop, since I think it only gets called after the commitAnimation.

Comment: I just want the view to slide over to the other each way. But do you see what I'm talking about? The gray bar goes from the middle to the bottom for no apparent reason.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the touch your choice button is starting off in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to lay out everything in a view animation before it starts. Fixed code below:

```
- (void)gotoMain_t{

NSLog(@"switch to main");

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

for(UIView *v in [containerView subviews]) {
    v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
}

MainMenu *mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(-1024, 0, 1024, 768);
[containerView insertSubview:mainMenu atIndex:1];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeT:finished:context:)];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.4];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(1024, 0, 1024, 768)];

    mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [mainMenu release];

} 

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Comment: i.e. notice that the frame are established for v and mainMenu before beginAnimations.

Answer (score 1):

Before `beginAnimations:`, try to set the coordinates of that gray bar to be at the end position. So CoreAnimation doesn't try to animate it. If that works, you could tweak its position so the animation looks nice at the end. It looks that somehow the y position of the gray bar changes to be mid screen.

Comment: It was actually that I did not lay out everything before I started the animation. Thanks!